# MariaDB 10.2.7 doesn't accept trailing Z for DATETIME timezone when inserting, but earlier version does

Tags: mariadb, datetime

It works with ADDTIME, but not when inserting.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT ADDTIME('2016-10-12T23:00:00Z', '1');
+--------------------------------------+
| ADDTIME('2016-10-12T23:00:00Z', '1') |
+--------------------------------------+
| 2016-10-12 23:00:01                  |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> INSERT INTO db.table (start) VALUES ('2016-10-12T23:00:00Z');
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2016-10-12T23:00:00Z' for column 'start' at row 1

MariaDB [(none)]> INSERT INTO db.table (start) VALUES ('2016-10-12T23:00:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Inserting with a trailing Z does work in another db that is 10.1.19.  What has changed?  It's valid ISO8601 as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB does not recognize your date format. In previous versions it autocorrefted value for you, but starting from version 10.2.4 MariaDB changed SQL mode to stricter and raises error instead of warning for faulty SQL queries.
If it's production, then temporary solution would be changing sql_mode to be not so strict. Change file /etc/my.cnf (on CentOS)

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
```

And restart mariadb service. I suggest you changing your query for MariaDB to fully understand it.
More info on sql_mode here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sql-mode/

Comment: Why does it not recognize it?  It's a valid ISO8601 date.

Comment: [More detailed answer](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13511)